# Serializing and deserializing and Python RTree

Tags: python, serialization, r-tree

I have been trying to debug some strange behaviour in a software package that uses [Pythons RTree version 0.8.2](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Rtree/).

In order to trace the problem, I need to serialize the RTree instance every few minutes, and when the problem happens I can have a pretty accurate snapshot of the RTree.

I am using the following code for the dump:

```python
def _dump_tree(self, filename, tree):
    try:
        dump_file = Rtree(filename)
        for item in tree.intersection(tree.bounds, objects=True):
            dump_file.insert(item.id, item.bbox, item.object)
    except RTreeError:
        pass
```

This function takes the RTree and copies it to a new RTree with a given filename.

Every invocation creates the following pairs:

```
2015-10-01---14-21-16_items.dat
2015-10-01---14-21-16_items.idx
...
```

How do I deserialize the `dat`/`idx` pairs back to Python objects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just open the RTree from the same filename:

```
>>> from rtree import index
>>> idx = index.Index('2015-10-01---14-21-16_items')
>>> idx.count(idx.bounds)
42 # The number of items you had in the original tree
```